# Fastest way to fill a scipy.sparse.dok_matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

What's the most efficient way to fill a scipy.sparse.dok_matrix, based on an input list ?

Neither the number of columns or rows in the dok_matrix are known in advance.

The number of rows is the length of the input list, the number of columns depends on the values within the input list.

The obvious:

```
def get_dok_matrix(values: List[Any]) -> scipy.sparse.dok_matrix:
    max_cols = 0
    datas = []
    for value in values:
        data = get_data(values)
        datas.append(data)
        if len(data) > max_cols:
            max_cols = len(data)
    dok_matrix = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((len(values), max_cols))
    for i, data in enumerate(datas):
        for j, datum in enumerate(data):
            dok_matrix[i, j] = datum
    return dok_matrix
```

Has two for loops, a nested for loop, and many `len()` checks also. I can't imagine this being very efficient.

I have also considered:

```
def get_dok_matrix(values: List[Any]) -> scipy.sparse.dok_matrix:
    cols = 0
    dok_matrix = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((0, 0))
    for row, value in enumerate(values):
        dok_matrix.resize(row + 1, cols)
        data = get_data(values)
        for col, datum in enumerate(data):
            if col + 1 > cols:
                cols = col + 1
                dok_matrix.resize(row + 1, cols)
            dok_matrix[row, col] = datum
    return dok_matrix
```

This hugely depends on how efficient `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.resize` is, which I couldn't find in the documentation.

Which of these is most efficient?

Is there a better way that I am missing (maybe I can O(1) set an entire row at once?)?

Comment: How about using the `coo` format instead?

Comment: @hpaulj why would it be better?

Comment: `dok` is ok for assigning values iteratively (as is `lil`), `coo` is the original input format, and works well if you can build the `data, row, col` arrays from arrays or lists.  With `coo` format you create 3 arrays, and call `coo_matrix` (or `csr`) just once.  It also takes care of identifying the max row and col values.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the the layout of your matrix.  You say `values` is a list; a list of what?  You iterate on `values`, but don't use `value`.  Instead you use `data = get_data(values)`.  How many data values per row?   The `j` enumeration suggests you filling the first `n` elements of the row.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
def get_dok_matrix(values):
    max_cols = 0
    datas = []
    for value in values:
        data = value         # changed
        datas.append(data)
        if len(data) > max_cols:
            max_cols = len(data)
    dok_matrix = sparse.dok_matrix((len(values), max_cols))
    for i, data in enumerate(datas):
        for j, datum in enumerate(data):
            dok_matrix[i, j] = datum
    return dok_matrix
```

And

```
In [13]: values = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12]]
In [14]: dd = get_dok_matrix(values)
In [15]: dd
Out[15]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 15 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [16]: dd.A
Out[16]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  0.],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.]])
```

I wish you'd provided a `values` example, so I wouldn't have to study your code and create one that would work with it.

To make a `coo` format:

```
def get_coo_matrix(values):
    data, row, col = [],[],[]
    for i,value in enumerate(values):
        n = len(value)
        data.extend(value)
        row.extend([i]*n)
        col.extend(list(range(n)))
    return sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row,col)))

In [18]: M = get_coo_matrix(values)
In [19]: M
Out[19]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 15 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [20]: M.A
Out[20]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  0],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

times:

```
In [22]: timeit dd = get_dok_matrix(values)
431 µs ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [23]: timeit M = get_coo_matrix(values)
152 µs ± 524 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```